# Date command is not working in remote server when running using a script

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, quoting, date

I am running below command from a script from a remote server, but getting error `No such file or directory`

```
ssh -t -t user@xx.xx.xx.xx \"sudo mysql nss_mysql < /home/user/scripts/Db_nss_mysql-`date +%Y-%m-%d`.sql && /bin/bash /home/user/scripts/jenkin-soft.sh\"
```

I run like `bash jenkin-soft.sh` and the complete error is:

```
jenkin-soft.sh: line 36: /home/user/scripts/Db_nss_mysql-`date +%Y-%m-%d`.sql: No such file or directory.
```

I tried below commands and they are working properly::

```
givinv@ser1:~/scripts$ ssh -t -t user@xx.xx.xx.xx "sudo mysql"
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 66

mysql> Bye
Connection to xx.xx.xx.xx closed.
givinv@ser1:~/scripts$ ssh -t -t  user@xx.xx.xx.xx "sudo ls /home/user/scripts/Db_nss_mysql-`date +%Y-%m-%d`.sql"
/home/user/scripts/Db_nss_mysql-2017-04-07.sql
Connection to xx.xx.xx.xx closed.
givinv@ser1:~/scripts$
```

What wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quoting is at fault here or rather the lack of it. Coz when you write:  \"sudo ....\" does not quote your string, rather it quotes that one quote char "

```
ssh -t -t user@xx.xx.xx.xx 'sudo mysql nss_mysql < /home/user/scripts/Db_nss_mysql-`date +%Y-%m-%d`.sql && /bin/bash /home/user/scripts/jenkin-soft.sh'
```